# Butter Knife @bind in Fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments, butterknife

I follow the instructions on the website : http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.project.myapp.OneFragment.

I try to remove `@Bind(R.id.btnNext) Button btnNext;` and run no error.

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
    @Bind(R.id.btnNext) Button btnNext;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static OneFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        OneFragment fragment = new OneFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your "fragment_one" layout. @Rufio Rocco

Comment: Use "getActivity()" not "this" in a fragment!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace this:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
```

with

```
ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(), view);
```