# Butter Knife @bind in Fragment Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-fragments, butterknife

After the problems were resolved. ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543276/butter-knife-bind-in-fragment-error/36543633#36543633))

I found a new problem attempt to invoke virtual method.

error : `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

But if the `ImageButton btnNext = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);` It work.

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
    @Bind(R.id.btnNext) ImageButton btnNext;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(), view);

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: put your fragment_one.xml

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to be binding the fragment not the activity.

```
ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
```